# How to remove extra paragraph breaks in Microsoft Word

Tags: microsoft-word

In the given photo you can see two paragraph breaks. I want to keep the break at the end of each paragraph but not the second one between paragraphs.

[image: screenshot showing the extra breaks]

Answer (score 0):

Simply delete the extra (blank) paragraphs. To all appearances, the paragraph format is set to have additional whitespace either before or after (or both); you don't need to insert extra blanks between paragraphs.

Answer (score 0):

Use Search and Replace and replace the doubled Paragraph Marks with a single Paragraph Mark.

Search for ^p^p

Replace with ^p

You can find them under the **Special** drop-down on the bottom of the dialog.